# How to write a Tf listener for a maniplutaor

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a help in writing a TF listner code for a manipulator, which will aid me in finding Forward and Inverse Kinematics. The TF listener tutorial is for turtlesim and i want to write a code for a manipulator.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296690/how-to-write-a-tf-listener-for-a-maniplutaor/) by [Sheby 99](https://answers.ros.org/users/36340/sheby-99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
this is almost the same as for the turtlesim. You can lookup the transformation between arbitrary coordinate frames. So, say you want to find the transformation from your end-effector `ee_link` to the base of the manipulator `base_link`. You can do this with (better place it in a try-catch enviroment):

```
  tf::StampedTransform transform;  
  listener.lookupTransform ("/ee_link", "/base_link", ros::Time::now(), transform);
```

However, first it would be helpful to open rviz and lookup the names of the coordinate frames, if you didn't do it so far.

I hope, I got your question right, if not, don't hesitate to ask again.

Cheers,
Matthias

Edit: It seems, that you have to complete a few steps more before you need the transformations served by ROS. At first, create a model of your robot. For this purpose you can use [Denavit–Hartenberg parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit%E2%80%93Hartenberg_parameters). This will help you to get the forward kinematikc. The inverse kinematic will be an optimization problem, which can't be solved in a closed form for a six axis robot like yours.

However, maybe you should have a look at this [Matlab toolbox by Peter Corke](http://petercorke.com/wordpress/toolboxes/robotics-toolbox). It is an open-source toolbox which will help you to learn a lot about your task.

Edit 2: Your Robot has 5 axis, not 6. But nonetheless, it should make no difference for you.

---

Originally posted by [matt_do](https://answers.ros.org/users/31551/matt_do/) with karma: 43 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sheby 99](https://answers.ros.org/users/36340/sheby-99/) on 2018-07-09**:
Thank you so much for the reply basically i have a Youbot Robot for which i have to find Forward and Inverse Kinematics. How would i know whether my TF is working right or not?
I am very new to ROS so kindly ur help will be highly appreciated.